# How to request a filepath in Django 1.7.1

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say i have a model in django called

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist_name = ...
    ...
    ...
    filename = models.FileField() /* This is wrong, don't know what to write here. */
```

I want to use filename to select a filepath of a song that's located somewhere on the disk.

I guess I can use a string to pass the filepath, but that's probably wrong. In any case if anyone has the answer i would really appreciate it.

EDIT

To clarify, what I want is to be able to choose the file path from the admin page, for example, when I'm at the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myapp/song/1/, I'd like to see:

```
Title     <textbox>
Artist    <textbox>
....
Filepath < and here i would select a file, like one selects a file from e.g. windows explorer>
```

`filename = models.FileField(`)  is wrong because i get an error:
 "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'filename' to song without a default;".
I typed this command just as an example of what I'm going for. I'm new to django and python so forgive me if I'm typing stupid things, just trying to get my point across.

Comment: you would like to trace the path of the file ?

Comment: Why is that wrong? Did you mean [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield)?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: The error you are describing is okay if you just added the filename field and are trying to make a migration to update your database. Just answer you are going to enter a default value and enter an empty string ''. That's it, it should work fine in your admin. If you then want to retrive the name of the uploaded file, do `song.filename.name`.  I would recommend you rename your field to `file` instead of `filepath`, because despite you are actually storing a path, you are using the model field to retrieve a `FieldFile` object.